# creating map/object parameter in cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a parameter in the cypher console with the following command:

```
:param props => { status: "closed" }
```

However, it's throwing me the error

[image]

Is it possible to create a map/object in the cypher console?

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-create-node-with-properties

indicates that it can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Neo4j Desktop 1.2.9 with Neo4j 4.0.4 it works [image]

But in other versions, you may try

```
:param props: {status:"closed"}
```

or

```
:param props: {"status":"closed"}
```

the latter being the equivalent of what is said in the manual you refer to.